# Solution of an ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given, $y^{\prime} = y^{3/5},y(0)=1$

Do $y$ has infinitely many solutions?

As, $y^{2/5}=(\frac{2}{5} x+1)$

Now, for any $\alpha\gt 0 $ , $f_{\alpha}=0$ ,when $(\frac{2}{5} x+1) \lt \alpha$

$f_{\alpha} = (\frac{2}{5} x+1-\alpha)^{2/5} $, when $ (\frac{2}{5} x+1)\ge \alpha$

So, got infinitely many solutions.

Comment: $f_\alpha$ needs to satisfy the initial condition. We have two case:

A) $5(\alpha-1)/2\le0\leftrightarrow\alpha\le1$: Then $f_\alpha(0)=(1-\alpha)^{5/2}=1\rightarrow\alpha=0$.

B) $5(\alpha-1)/2>0\leftrightarrow\alpha>1$: Then $f_\alpha(0)=0\ne1$.

Thus the other solution is $$f_\alpha=\begin{cases}0,&x<-5/2\\(2x/5+1)^{5/2},&x\ge-5/2\end{cases}$$

Comment: @Shubham Johri the main answer is , $y$ have unique solution here,,,how could it possible even??!!

Comment: @Shubham Johri sorry for the late response!!

Comment: Note that your first solution $(2x/5+1)^{5/2}$ is not valid for $x<-5/2$.

Comment: @Shubham Johri please provide a suitable answer, I have to clear the concept.